# How to use iOS simulator/Android simulator from visual studio for Mac with xamarian.forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, azure, mono

I made mobile app at azure and quickstarted it as xamarian.forms and (after failing to publish downloaded table api application and deciding to edit it in browser) downloaded the client application they provided. Then when I tried to launch it with on (Debug>IPhone 8 Plus iOS 11.2) simulator, it (simulator) started but no application is visible (and nothing unusual is installed).

It shows warnings (could it be relevant?):

Warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190. (MSB3276)

(For Android simulator it gives some error like:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.1/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/NuGet/Microsoft.NuGet.targets(5,5): Error: Your project is not referencing the "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0" framework. Add a reference to "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0" in the "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore.
)

How can I see the ****** application?
Thank you. =)

Comment: I should have mentioned, that I am completely new to Xamarian, iOS development and almost new to android development.
And downloading windows in background =)

Answer (score 0):

Open the project.json file in your xxx.Droid project. Change the MonoAndroid version from:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1": {}
  }
```

to:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0": {}
  }
```

Now, Restore Nuget Packages for your solution.

Comment: Yes, I think that was an action that helped in the end, Thank you

Comment: @leem could you please tell me where is this project.json file is?
I am having an issue in MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0. It says that I need to add it there